# Unable to block packets to Guest OS with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, bridge

> My home workstation is running a windows OS Guest Machine with bridged
>   connection to br-ex ( OVS bridge).
>   enp0s25 is the LAN NIC connected to br-ex ovs bridge.   Host OS has IP
>   194.168.1.4 and Guest OS with 194.168.1.5. With iptables on host, everything is blocked in and out except SSH. But still I am able to
>   connect to Guest OS (194.168.1.5) with RDP. I am trying to figure out what is allowing it.

```
[root@workstation ~]# ovs-vsctl show
35d1e142-cf99-44de-85e7-f21276acd9dc
    Bridge test-br
        Port test-br
            Interface test-br
                type: internal
    Bridge br-ex
        Port "vnet0"
            Interface "vnet0"
        Port br-ex
            Interface br-ex
                type: internal
        Port "enp0s25"
            Interface "enp0s25"
    ovs_version: "2.9.3"
[root@workstation ~]#

5: br-ex: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:ea:a7:5e:54:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 194.168.1.4/24 brd 194.168.1.255 scope global br-ex
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9cd2:bdff:fe7f:947/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[root@workstation ~]# iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  localhost            anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh ctstate ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             localhost
```

Comment: Are you trying to block everything in and out of guest?

Comment: No, I could have used bridge only for that, but here I wanted to allow some ports only but currently looks like everything is open, which is not expected as per the iptables config.

Comment: http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/faq/issues/ "Q: Open vSwitch does not seem to obey my packet filter rules." see the comment about ebtables (yes, to filter on a bridge, it's at bridge level with ebtables, not at router/host level with iptables. iptables can do this when [br_netfilter](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) is loaded, but it's an ugly hack, probably not compatible with OVS).